# How to insert values into table by using inner query as select statement using Python Flask and PyOdbc? Input of Inner queries fetched from HTML form

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, pyodbc

Environment Details. Windows 10 - Python3.5 - Flask - SQL SERVER - PyOdbc.

```
cur.execute("insert into T1 (ID_CUSTOMER, ID_ENVIRONMENT) values (?, ?)",
                    select id from CUSTOMER where name = form['customerId'],
                    select id from ENVIRONMENT where name = form['environmentId'],
                    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `values`, you can directly use `INSERT SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO T1 
            (ID_CUSTOMER, 
             ID_ENVIRONMENT) 
SELECT ID_CUSTOMER =(SELECT Max(id) 
                     FROM   customer 
                     WHERE  NAME = 'abc'), 
       ID_ENVIRONMENT = (SELECT Max(id) 
                         FROM   environment 
                         WHERE  NAME = 'xyz')
```

The `Max(id)` here is to make sure the inner query returns a single value